# How to get access token just after login in successHandler in spring oauth2 security?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0

Currently, I am working on a project where a requirement is **accessToken** need to be collected at spring success handler just after login. I read different blogs but couldn't found any possible solution. Here I am giving code snippet that I tried,

This is my success handler where I am trying to get accessToken. But when I am trying to cast **authentication.getDetails()** to **OAuth2AuthenticationDetails** I am getting exception.

```
@Component
public class AuthSuccessListener implements ApplicationListener<AuthenticationSuccessEvent> {
  
    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(AuthenticationSuccessEvent event) {
     
        UserDetails userDetails = (UserDetails) event.getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
        System.out.println(userDetails);
        System.out.println("pass is " + userDetails.getPassword());
        System.out.println("username is " + userDetails.getUsername());

        Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
       //Authentication authentication = event.getAuthentication();


        OAuth2AuthenticationDetails details = (OAuth2AuthenticationDetails) authentication.getDetails();
        String accessToken = details.getTokenValue();
        System.out.println(accessToken);
        
    }
}
```

I don't know whether this approach is valid or not. If there any other way to get accessToken just after login in successHandler or somewhere else, then please help to solve this issue.

Comment: We have done similar in our application, will follow this question for better way :)

Comment: @code_mechanic I solved that issue in short. And I posted that solution in my answer. You can check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least I found a solution to get token at succeshandler just after login. As I haven't got relevant solution in short, that's why I am posting this answer. I solved the issue like this.

```
    @Component
    public class AuthSuccessListener implements ApplicationListener<AuthenticationSuccessEvent> {
    
        private final TokenStore tokenStore;
    
        public AuthSuccessListener(TokenStore tokenStore) {
            this.tokenStore = tokenStore;
        }
    
        @Override
        public void onApplicationEvent(AuthenticationSuccessEvent event) {
            UserDetails userDetails = (UserDetails) event.getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
            String accessToken = null;
            List<OAuth2AccessToken> tokens = (List<OAuth2AccessToken>) tokenStore.findTokensByClientIdAndUserName("your Client Id", userDetails.getUsername());
            if (tokens.size() > 0) {
                accessToken = tokens.get(0).getValue();
            }
        }
    }
```

Here you can see I used **TokenStore** to reteive token by using **clientId** and **username** with method `tokenStore.findTokensByClientIdAndUserName("your Client Id", userDetails.getUsername());`
That's it.

Comment: But you are querying to DB to get the value back, is this ok to you?

Comment: @code_mechanic That **TokenStore** is spring-security provided. I have just called it. And got the exact token as provided by `/oauth/token`

Comment: Do you know why it gives the `List` ?

Comment: @code_mechanic There may be a configuration where can be multiple accessToken for a client. That's what I assume. That's why that method returns `Collection`

Comment: @AvijitBarua I can't see any class like TokenStore by spring security, which version did you use?

Comment: What exactly is client-id?